# Fetch as Google not reading all source code

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, fetch-as-google

I just did a Google Webmaster Tools fetch test on two websites and found that Google is not reading all source code of one of them.

Here Google is not taking my website `<title>`, `<meta>`. Google is directly starting from website categories and shows only Links not even their Description and Title.

- My website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcIVy.png
- My friends website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TjzS.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Your mistaken, Google can see your code, in the fetch test you are suppose to have a horizontal scroll bar and in the screenshot you do not, which would indicate a browser issue, not a Google, or website.

Also, the reason you can see your friends code is because his code is clean (beautified) and yours is a mess. If you fix your browser issue, or use a different browser and look on line 21, scroll right your see your code there.

Comment: Thankyou i am able to see Full code now. But we are using Same browser which is Android Google chrome, but 1 thing is different i.e He is loolipop user while i am kitkat 4.4.2 user. Anyways Thankyou :-)